# How to disabled scroll when a textview is edited?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UIScrollView in wich I have a little UITextView in the middle and a Button on the bottom.
When I press the button, I would like to edit the UItextView and then scroll to the top. The thing is, when I press the button, the UITextView is edited in the code, then it automatically scroll to the beggining of this UITextView and ignores the line of code where I do the scrolling to the top.

```
- (IBAction)SubmitForm:(id)sender {
    if ([Titre.text length] == 0 || [TypeIntervention.text length] == 0 || [Client.text length] == 0) {
      ErrorMsg.text = @"test";
      [self.Scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.Scroll.contentOffset.x, 0)animated:YES];
    }
    else {
      DoneMsg.text = @"test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement **UITextView delegates** and use **scrollEnabled** property of UIScrollView

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    self.Scroll.scrollEnabled = NO;

    return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    self.Scroll.scrollEnabled = NO;

}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    self.Scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    self.Scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;;
}
```

Comment: I did delegate the UITextView to my ViewController.m and then add this code at the end, but still when I press the button, the UItextView changes and the UIScrollView scrolls to the UITextView.

Comment: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861404/how-to-make-a-uiscrollview-with-a-uitextview-sub-view-not-scroll-when-adding-tex?rq=1